# I cannot connect to bootstrap

Tags: html, css, web

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <h1 class="header">My Booklist</h1> <br>
    <body>
        <form>
            
            <input class="book"></input><br><br>
            <input class="author"></input><br><br>
            <input class="isbn"></input><br><br>
            <button class="btn">Submit</button>
    
         </form>
            <br>
            <br>
           <!-- <table  class="tbl" >
                <tr >
                    <th>book</th>
                    <th>author</th> 
                    <th>isbn</th>
                  </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="table"> -->
      <thead  class="tbl">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
           
    </body>
        
    </html>
```

please help me I am stuck because of this issue while learning. I have tried downloading and adding CDN but nothing is working for me to connect bootstrap. I have been trying to make an app using HTML, CSS, js but stuck in this very silly problem.
please help me I am stuck because of this issue while learning. I have tried downloading and adding CDN but nothing is working for me to connect bootstrap. I have been trying to make an app using HTML, CSS, js but stuck in this very silly problem.

Comment: One place to start troubleshooting your problem would be to clean up your HTML code, which has a number of errors (an h1 tag before the body tag; a closing tag on `</input>` (not valid); your table tag is commented out; and you’re trying to load jQuery and Bootstrap JS after the `</body>` closing tag (should be before))

Answer (score 0):

Write the JavaScript CDNs just above the closing of the body tag. Try the code I wrote and you will see it works.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<h1 class="header">My Booklist</h1> <br>

<body>
    <form>

        <input class="book"></input><br><br>
        <input class="author"></input><br><br>
        <input class="isbn"></input><br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- <table  class="tbl" >
            <tr >
                <th>book</th>
                <th>author</th> 
                <th>isbn</th>
              </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table"> -->
    <thead class="tbl">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems ok except JavaScript cdn version. Your bootstrap css version is 5.0.0 where as your JavaScript version is 3.4.1.

You can update your "atest compiled JavaScript" cdn to

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I pray this fix may help you. Thank you.